# Liver fibrosis score as dependent variable in multivariable logistic regression that includes elements of the score as independent variables

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, dependent-variable

There is an index for liver fibrosis called the FIB-4 score which is calculated from blood concentrations of the liver function enzymes AST and ALT, platelet count and age. The score is included in different algorithms used as screening for non-invasively predicting patients with advanced fibrosis. We are considering a multivariable logistic regression using one of those algorithms (as a proxy for the presence of advanced liver disease) as the dependent variable in an analysis that includes the factors in the FIB-4 score (AST, ALT, age and platelet count). With the exception of age and the liver enzymes, all these factors are highly correlated with another (P<.001 in most cases). I think this violates basics and is inadvisable. What do you think? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To say “using one of the algorithms [...] as the dependent variable“ is imprecise wording and actually doesn’t make sense. Perhaps you meant “using the FIB-4....”

What is the purpose of this regression?  To show the degree to which the FIB-4 index depends on each of its inputs, or building blocks?  If so then one would hope to see some high correlations. These would be indicated by the strength — of r, partial r, semipartial r, b, or beta — more than by p, which depends so much on the sample size.

It is hard to see how binary logistic regression would apply. The FIB-4 sounds like an interval-level variable, in which case linear regression would be a natural choice. If FIB-4 is nominal—unusual for such an index—then multinomial logistic regression would probably apply. If you are dichotomizing interval-level scores into a binary Disease/No Disease variable, it would be a great loss of fine-grained information and would call for special justification.

If the purpose is to predict each patient’s FIB-4 score as a proxy for liver disease, then using the inputs to that score as predictors would accomplish little. It would seem to be circular.

Examples abound of clinicians or clinician-researchers trying to conduct such analyses without calling on statisticians or data analysts, or calling on them too late, with unhappy results. I hope your team is not heading down that road.

Comment: Right, sorry - let me be more specific. The algorithm is one developed by McPherson et al, Am J Gastroenterology 2017;112:740, which is binary, predicting where fibrosis is likely or not. Another is Ciardullo, Diabetes Research and Clinical Practice, 2020; 167:108358, which uses FIB-4 and AST. Binary logistic does not apply. The dependent variable is composed of elements of the independent variables, it is circular. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @JuanTamad - to make this page useful to people, I hope you’ll state the purpose of the analysis.

Comment: The purpose is evaluate noninvasive methods for determining whether a person might have liver fibrosis. The dependent variable is  not 'FIB4' but some other scoring formulas (algorithms) that might include the FIB4. These others have been developed because the FOB4 is not as accurate as you'd like. Your last paragraph is relevant in this case.